# White flash between page loads

Tags: javascript, css, image-preloader

I am finishing up a site and getting some white flashes between page loads. I tried preloading all the big images to see if that was the problem but still not getting smooth transitions. All my css and js files seem to be loading in the correct order as well. Any ideas? The site was build on the Wordpress CMS with a full screen background plugin.

js pre load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( function(){
    $.preload( '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/badge.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/bg.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/header.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/eagle_header.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/paper_header.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/left_badge.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/right.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/left.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/footer.png',
              '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/logo.png'
    );
 });
</script>
```

[The Site](http://www.revolveis.net/watkins/)

Comment: Your CMS is generating some broken HTML. A quick look at the page source in Firefox shows some nesting problems with DIVS. Your background images are huge (~1.3Mb for the eagle) - try reducing the size of the images if you can. Lastly, the browsers aren't caching some static resources (mostly images) properly. Look at adding some caching controls to .htaccess

Comment: And a PS - you're loading several Javascript files in the <head>. These will block the rest of the page loading until they've executed. You should move them to the bottom of the <body> if possible.

Comment: @MikeW Thanks. Some of the plugins load in the wordpress head so I cant move them to the footer. I will make some images smaller and look at caching controls (never used those). I didnt see any broken html in chrome inspector, could you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: From line 198 to line 219 of the source code of your home page FF is reporting `No space between attributes` and `End tag "div" seen but there were open elements` There are a lot of DIVs so it's difficult to tell exactly where the problem starts. These are line numbers in the final generated page - I have no idea where that might be in your CMS.